# How to obtain the href link using css selectors

Tags: css-selectors, scrapy

I am trying to make a crawler to crawl images on imgur. I am having trouble selecting the element I want to select. I am attempting to select the href link for each image on the home page. The home url is: https://imgur.com/t/memes/
If anyone knows the correct css selector to get the specific href link for each image that would be great!

For further clarification, I need to select the link in the href : [here is the html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGJxy.png). Does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
a.Grid-item::attr(href)
```

breakdown:

`a` - select  node.
`.Grid-item` - that has class "Grid-item".
`::attr(href)` - select attribute href of current node.